# Image in the ImageView not displaying well in GalaxyS4

Tags: android, imageview, galaxy

In my application i am showing images by using ImageView but in Galaxy s4 the image is moving to left-top like the below image. In remaining devices its working well but i can't understand why its not working for S4 only. Please give a suggesstion.

note: I am using grey color image in the layout under src tag and replacing it with setImageBitmap() in the activity.

[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your layout.

Comment: No its confidential. But i think its not the problem with layout because the same layout is working for different urls which are very less in size.

Comment: You could show your layout xml without compromising your data, the problem is likely in your layout. Check padding and weight, does it appear normal in other phones with same screen size etc etc? Need more info here

Comment: Yes Pontus it is looking good in the remaining devices without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you using ImageBitmap??? it takes a lot of memory and doesn't free it even when it lost the reference.

For performance reasons, you should go for ImageDrawable..

and Yes, you have to share at least the xml layout so that others can check the problem.

You are doing like you won't open your pants in front of Doctor even when you have stritches on your thigh just because you feel shy.